# How to change the FrameworkElement to Image in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, frameworkelement

I have `FrameworkElement` with my hand, it is having parent also. I want change it as `Image` in WinRT platform. I tried the `WriteableBitmap`. But it does have element parameter to render. `VisualBrush` also not available here.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT doesn't have a means to create a bitmap from a visual - at least in the current preview. See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/8fcc3e34-13cd-4742-b4c9-c3c65e79f8b7) on the WinRT forums for more.